# Delete record from TableAdapter - Problems

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to delete a record from my DataGridView and consequently from the database. I'm using the following code:

```
 Me.TransactionBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
 Me.TransactionBindingSource.EndEdit()
 Me.TransactionTableAdapter.Update(Me.DbPBDataSet)
```

However, I'm having further problems with the .Update method in my triggers when I keep logs of the deleted records. Is there any way I can delete the record without calling that particular method?